# How to implement Softmax regression with pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, regression, softmax

I am working on a uni assignment where I need to implement `Softmax Regression` with `Pytorch`. The assignment says:

```
Implement Softmax Regression as an nn.Module and pipe its output with its output with torch.nn.Softmax.
```

As I am new to pytorch, I am not sure how to do it exactly. So far I have tried:

class SoftmaxRegression(nn.Module):  # inheriting from nn.Module!

```
def __init__(self, num_labels, num_features):

    super(SoftmaxRegression, self).__init__()
    self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(num_labels, num_features)

def forward(self, x):
    # should return the probabilities for the classes, e.g.
    # tensor([[ 0.1757,  0.3948,  0.4295],
    #         [ 0.0777,  0.3502,  0.5721], 
    #         ...

    # not sure what to do here
```

does anybody have any idea how I could go about it? I am not sure what should be written in the `forward` method. I appreciate any help !

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, the assignment wants you to implement your own version of the Softmax function. But, I didn't get what do you mean by `and pipe its output with torch.nn.Softmax`. Are they asking you to return the output of your custom Softmax along with `torch.nn.Softmax` from your custom `nn.Module`? You could do this:

```py
class SoftmaxRegression(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dim=0):
        super(SoftmaxRegression, self).__init__()
        self.dim = dim
    def forward(self, x):
        means = torch.mean(x, self.dim, keepdim=True)[0]
        exp_x= torch.exp(x-means)
        sum_exp_x = torch.sum(exp_x, self.dim, keepdim=True)
        value = exp_x/sum_exp_x
        return value
```